# Search data from FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: vb.net

How can I make my textbox.text when I enter something to fetch results in `flowlayoutpanel` and if i remove text form textbox to show all again.
Simply search option inside the flowpanel to show found records.

The code that create the `flowlayoutpanel` when form loads:

```
Private Sub GenerateDynamicUserControl()
    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New ClassBLL().GetItems()

    If dt IsNot Nothing Then

        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim listItems As ListItem() = New ListItem(dt.Rows.Count - 1) {}

            For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1

                For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    Dim listItem As New ListItem()
                    listItems(i) = listItem
                    'Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(row("userPic"), Byte()))
                    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(CType(row("UserPictureFrom"), Byte()))
                    Dim ms2 As New MemoryStream(CType(row("UserPictureTo"), Byte()))
                    listItems(i).Width = FlowLayoutPanel1.Width - 30
                    listItems(i).Icon = New Bitmap(ms)
                    listItems(i).Icon2 = New Bitmap(ms2)
                    listItems(i).OrderFrom = row("orderfrom").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderTitle = row("UserPositionFrom").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderReceiver = row("orderreceiver").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderTitle2 = row("UserPositionTo").ToString()
                    'listItems(i).ButtonBackground = orderButtonBackString
                    listItems(i).ButtonText = row("orderstatus").ToString()
                    listItems(i).OrderDate = row("orderdate")
                    listItems(i).IDOrder = row("orderid").ToString()
                    listItems(i).Subject = row("ordersubject").ToString()
                    listItems(i).SubjectText = row("ordersubjecttext").ToString()

                    If listItems(i).ButtonText = "Accepted" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(26, 168, 92)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Declined" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(246, 50, 90)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Proceed" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 174, 33)
                    ElseIf listItems(i).ButtonText = "Waiting" Then
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(53, 121, 255)
                    Else
                        listItems(i).ButtonBackground = Color.FromArgb(91, 146, 255)
                    End If
                    FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(listItems(i))
                Next
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The class:

```
Public Function ReadItemsTable() As DataTable
    Using cons As New SQLiteConnection(ServerStatus)
        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand()
            cmd.Connection = cons
            'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM OrdersAssigned ORDER BY ID ASC"
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT OrdersAssigned.*,
              ProfilesFrom.userPosition AS UserPositionFrom,
              ProfilesFrom.userPicture AS UserPictureFrom,
              ProfilesTo.userPosition AS UserPositionTo,
              ProfilesTo.userPicture AS UserPictureTo
            FROM
              (OrdersAssigned
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Profiles AS ProfilesFrom ON OrdersAssigned.orderacc = ProfilesFrom.userAccount)
              LEFT OUTER JOIN Profiles AS ProfilesTo ON OrdersAssigned.orderreceiveracc = ProfilesTo.userAccount
            ORDER BY
              OrdersAssigned.ID ASC;"
            cons.Open()
            Using sda As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
                Dim dt As New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)
                Return dt
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

and on my button "btnSearchOrders_TextChanged" I need to input the search method any ideas how to do that without calling new query?

Comment: `btnSearchOrders_TextChanged` You want this to run when the Button text changes?

Comment: Does the code in the first block have anything to do with the code in the second block?

Comment: `For i As Integer = 0 To 1 - 1` What is the point of this?

Comment: DataTable.Select method may help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-6.0#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_  Does not require another hit on the database.

Comment: yes the point is from button textchanged event when write something to match it in the flowlayoutpanel that has inside, ex: name, position, subject everything as text

Answer (score 0):

On the textbox TextChanged event try something like:

```
  For Each myControl As Control In myflowlayoutcontrol.Controls
    If myControl.text=mytextboxname.text then
      'found it!
    End if
    'more code goes here
  Next
```

the code inside the .TextChanged function will run every time the text of the textbox change and will search for the text on it in the flow control objects .text strings.

Let me know if you need more help.